# Help me to understand how to write a function in jQuery

Tags: jquery, events

I am able to reverse engineer jQuery, but I now have to learn how to forward engineer.  I know how to write JavaScript functions, and I know that within JavaScript functions, you can use jQuery.  However, I am really stuck with trying to make a function out of the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function doStuff( bar )
    {
        // Match all <A/> links with a title tag and use it as the content (default).
        $('.graph').qtip({
            content: {
                text: 'Loading...', // The text to use whilst the AJAX request is loading
                ajax: {
                    url: '/foo/' + bar , // URL to the local file
                    type: 'GET', // POST or GET
                    data: {} // Data to pass along with your request
                }
            },
            show: {
                solo: "true",
                delay: 100,
                event: "click",
                adjust : {screen : true}
            },
        });
    }
});
```

This code works great, but only if I remove the

```
function doStuff( bar )
{
}
```

The reason that I want to wrap that stuff in a function is so that I can pass in a parameter.  Like I said, I can work with jQuery, but I am far from a master.  Any help or advice/critique of my strategy is welcome.

Edit

This is where I call the function.  Thanks for all the help too!

```
<a class="graph" title="a_link_title" href="#" onclick="doStuff('281'); return false;"> a link </a>
```

Comment: reverse engineer jQuery? WTF man!

Comment: The document ready function doesn't provide any parameters, what are you looking to pass to your method?

Comment: @Pablo Fernandez I mean start with code that is already written, and figure out what is going on and mimmick it

Comment: @Clayton: `.ready()` does provide one argument for which you can define a parameter. The argument is the global jQuery function itself, so you can define an alias inside the ready callback.

Comment: @clayton I just want to pass in an integer.  I will use the integer to create a url that I will make an ajax call to.  I REALLY just want to create a simple function with the 'content' and 'show' sections inside.  Is that possible without the document.ready??

Comment: @Chris , check my answer , as your function is not getting executed on document.ready ,you are not seeing the results , move that function out and call it inside document.ready

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing

this function shouldn't be inside document.ready

```
 function doStuff( bar )
 {

 }
```

The code is not executing because of htis function , unless you call this function it doesn't work.

You can do two things. call the function or remove the function and move out of document.ready and call it inside document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   doStuff(bar) // pass the value and call it like this
});

    function doStuff( bar )
    {
        // Match all <A/> links with a title tag and use it as the content (default).
        $('.graph').qtip({
            content: {
                text: 'Loading...', // The text to use whilst the AJAX request is loading
                ajax: {
                    url: '/foo/' + bar , // URL to the local file
                    type: 'GET', // POST or GET
                    data: {} // Data to pass along with your request
                }
            },
            show: {
                solo: "true",
                delay: 100,
                event: "click",
                adjust : {screen : true}
            },
        });
    }
```

Comment: @patrick , in his case, he is not calling that function and may be that is reason why his remaining code is not getting executed.

Comment: Yes, you're right that he needs to call the function, but whether it's located in the ready callback or not won't make a difference, unless he's also trying to invoke it from a different variable environment.

Comment: @patrick , thats true , i was under impression that he is not calling that function

Comment: I am calling the function in the onclick of the link.  This solution makes sense, but it is not working as of yet.  But do you more knowledge jquery'ers agree that this solution would work?  Thanks all.

Comment: @Chris, you might have binded your click event in document.ready only right, why don't you move this method out of document.ready and give a try

Comment: @kobe: +1 as it seems that it is invoked inline. (That's my guess anyway.)

Comment: @kobe.  I have tried that.  Shouldn't I be able to completely eliminate the document.ready portion?  I cobbled together knowledge from a bunch of tutorials, and came up with that code.  Thank you so much.

Comment: @Chris , try to moveout the global functions out of document.ready , in that way it will be cleaner and you can call that function from any other place , document.ready should be used exclusively for onload events and onload code execution

Comment: @patrick , if you don't mind , i just looked at your profile and your age says 91 , is that real? answer only if you don't mind

Comment: @Chris: If there's code that's relevant to your issue, you should include it in your question. For example, if you're trying to invoke this function as an inline `onclick=doStuff();`, that would be a relevant piece of the puzzle. If you're trying to bind it with jQuery, that will likely require a different solution. The way your question currently reads, you've created the function, but haven't invoked it anywhere.

Comment: kobe: That's real only in the sense that that's sometimes how old I feel at the end of the day. In other words, no. ;o)

Comment: @Chris , thats true as patrick mentioned post the code where you are invoking this function that will help us

Comment: @patrick , nice answer kool , just want to say a thank you to you as i have learnt a lot from many of your answers and thats the reason i visited your profile , keep up the good work of sharing knowledge

Comment: Added the code that I am using to invoke the function.  As a test, I alerted "hello", and the message appears, but no tooltip.  perplexing!  And I added the alert at the very beginning of the function, and at the very end.  It works at both places

Answer (score 0):

**Quick fix:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function doStuff(bar) {
        // your code
    }

    doStuff(123); // might help to actually call your function! :-)

});
```